# zend how to use same view in multiple action?

Tags: zend-framework

I need to use the same view for an edit action and add action. Do i need to create separate views for this. My forms are same. Is it possible to use same view in different actions? if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this in your controller code: `$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setRender('add');` in your edit action. It will use the add.phtml view for it's action.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your common view scripts in any subdirectory of the `application/views/scripts` directory (assuming you are using the standard Zend Framework directory structure).

For instance, if you use the `application/views/scripts/common` subdirectory, you can call your view script called `common.phtml` from your actions, using

```
$this->renderScript('common/common.phtml');
```

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

You can set the view script in the controller using

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('another/view/script.phtml')
```